# Why am I getting a run- tme error & can you correct it?

Tags: vbscript

The program does what I want it to do, but I'm getting the run-time error. I'm not a programmer so I'm asking for help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("a1:a10")
        If (cell.Value) = "0" Then
            Range("b" & Target.Row).Clear
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please let us know what kind of run-time error do you get.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error 28 is infinite recursion, caused by `Clear()` which leads to subsequent `Worksheet_Change` execution.

As a quick dirty fix you could use a global `Boolean` variable to skip excessive `Clear()` call.

```
Public isChanging As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If isChanging = False Then
        isChanging = True

        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Range("a1:a10")
            If (cell.Value) = "0" Then
                Range("b" & cell.Row).Clear
            End If
        Next

        isChanging = False
    End If
End Sub
```